# Why doesn't my buttons work?

Tags: flash-cc

I have a perculiar situation here, usually I have no problems with this.

The situation is like this, I have 4 screens. A game screen, a menu and a win screen and a death screen.

the situation is that the buttons that allow my player to go from the win screen to the menu is not working. I traced it and the button is working, it just doesn't move the frames.

here are the codes I used.

```
    public function prototype() {

    }
    public function startMenu() {
        btnStart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoGame);
    }
    public function gotoGame(evt: MouseEvent): void {
        btnStart.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoGame);
        gotoAndStop("game1");
    }
    public function gotoGameA(evt: MouseEvent): void {
        btnContinue.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoGameA);
        btnMenu.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoFront);
        gotoAndStop("game1");
    }
    public function gotoWin() {
        gotoAndStop("win");
        startWin()
    }
    public function startWin() {
        btnContinue.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoGameA);
        btnMenu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoFront);
    }
    public function gotoFront(evt: MouseEvent): void {
        trace("please work")
        gotoAndStop("menu");
        startMenu();
    }
    public function gotoDeath() {
        gotoAndPlay("death");
    }
```

I am not sure what to do with this.

Timeline:

[image]

Comment: without a timeline, it's hard to know you config this right / wrong. Also, where do you put this piece of code?

Comment: I tried posting the image of the timeline, but I don't have enough points. I placed the code in the main script of the game.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10204164673536095&set=a.10204164673176086.1073741832.1204000217&type=3&permPage=1

Comment: Added the image for you. Your ActionScript should be placed at the 1st frame (better on a separate layer with only 1 keyframe on frame 1). Try.

Comment: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.at prototype/gotoFront() Gotoand play still did not work.

Comment: Setup your objects (`prototype`) on Frame 1.

Comment: @KriegerNg If you solved it, please post your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function startMenu() {
            btnStart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoGame);
        }

        private function gotoGame(evt: MouseEvent) {
            btnStart.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoGame);
            gotoAndStop("game1");
        }
        private function gotoGameA(evt: MouseEvent) {
            btnContinue.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoGame);
            btnMenuA.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoMenu);
            gotoAndStop("game1");
        }
        public function startGameWin() {
            btnMenuA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoMenu);
            btnContinue.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoGameA);
        }

        public function startGameOver() {
            btnMenuB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoMenuA);
        }

        private function gotoMenu(evt: MouseEvent) {
            trace("hit")
            btnMenuA.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoMenu);
            btnContinue.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoGame);
            gotoAndStop("game1");
            gotoAndStop("menu");
        }
        private function gotoMenuA(evt: MouseEvent) {
            trace("hit")
            btnMenuB.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoMenuA);
            gotoAndStop("game1");
            gotoAndStop("menu");
        }
```